# Gathering `kafka.producer` metrics using JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I have a Kakfa broker running, which I am monitoring with JMX.

This broker is a docker container running as a process started with `kafka-server-start.sh` JMX port `9999` is exposed as and used as an environment variables.

When I connect to the JMX port and try to list all the domains, I get the following;

```
kafka
kafka.cluster
kafka.controller
kafka.coordinator.group
kafka.coordinator.transaction
kafka.log
kafka.network
kafka.server
kafka.utils
```

I dont see `kafka.producer` which is understandable because the producer for this Kafka broker are `N` numbers of different applications, but at this point I am confused.

How do I get the `kafka.producer` metrics as well.
Do I have to expose the `kafka.producer` metrics in each of `N` application that is acting as producer **OR** is there some configuration that start gathering `kafka.producer` metrics on the broker only.

What is the correct way of doing this. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are correct , to capture the producer JMX metrics , you need to enable JMX in all the processes which are running the kafka producer instance.

Comment: Hey, I am new to Kafka & I wanted to capture the producer rate in my local setup. I am running my producer from IDE which is expected to produce a million records to the topic. In this case, how can I expose the kafka.producer metrics to capture the metrics?

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to rephrase **producing** as **writing over an unreliable network** in this context.

From this perspective, the most reasonable place to measure *writing characteristics* seems to be the client itself (i.e. in each "application" as you call it).

If messages between the producer and the broker are lost, you can still send stats to a local "metric store" for example (e.g. you could see a "spike" in `record-retry-rate` or some other relevant metric).

Additionally, pairing Kafka producer metrics with additional, **local** metrics might be extremely useful (JVM stats, detailed business metrics and so on). Keep in mind, that the client will almost definitely run on a different machine in a production environment, and might be affected by different factors, than the broker itself.

If you intend to monitor your client application (which will most likely happen anyway), then I'd simply do it there (i.e. the [standard](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#producer-metrics) way).