# Kafka Producer Metrics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx, kafka-producer-api

I am running a Kafka producer in a local machine using my Intellij IDE & the producer will be producing a million records. While doing so, I want to capture the producer metrics in the below way:

[image]

I am aware about JMX port for kafka & I did try setting the Kafka JMX port to 9999.
But I am not sure if we can get the metrics using JConsole or JVisualVM in the above way that I am expecting.

Can any one suggest any idea as to how can this be achieved?

Comment: look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985430/gathering-kafka-producer-metrics-using-jmx

Comment: @KenrySanchez I had a look at the post. I had added a comment there as well. It's just that I am unable to figure how to enable the producer metrics or rather how can I get it in the above manner

Comment: I think Elastic Stack can do that.  Kafka + Elastic Stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition of JMX, the official Kafka clients also expose their metrics via the Java API, see the [`metrics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#metrics--) method to retrieve them all.

For example, to print all the metrics' names and values:

```java
for (Entry<MetricName, ? extends Metric> entry : producer.metrics().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey().name() + " : " + entry.getValue().metricValue());
}
```

Out of all the metrics, you are probably interested in `outgoing-byte-rate`, `request-total` and `request-rate`.

Comment: Thanks for this API ! I wasn't aware about it. However I am trying to accumulate stats checking for 10k records, then 100k and so on as mentioned in the question. I tried printing the metrics, but its giving me an overall metric while I wanted it at specific intervals. How can this be achieved with the API?

Comment: You'll have to call it at specific intervals explicitly, it's easy to count records.

Comment: It would be great if you can help me with posting a snippet of calling it at specific intervals.

Comment: Is there any way to get the ````Request total time```` from ````kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=TotalTimeMs,request={Produce|FetchConsumer|FetchFollower}```` using the Metrics java API?
Thanks