# How to measure the number of messages produced by kafka producer per second?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am learning Kafka for my university project, I would like to know the logging technique to monitor number of messages produced per second by Kafka producer.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of Kafka metrics that are exposed on JMX. You can check the official docs [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html) for that. As you can see there, one of the Producer metrics is `request-rate` (the average number of requests sent per second.). You just need to enable JMX in the producer client JVM. Some more helpful info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985430/gathering-kafka-producer-metrics-using-jmx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016032/kafka-producer-metrics).